# LWJGL Voxel Engine - Textures on VBO's

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, vbo, voxel

I am currently working on a Voxel Engine similar to that of Minecraft. Recently I have been attempting to implement textures into the system. My system uses a texture atlas and coord system, however I have been experiencing problems such as the program crashing on launch with just "Java is not responding" and if it does launch the blocks have no texture. So how would I fix my code to solve these errors and implement textures properly. Thanks!

Chunk Class:

```
public class Chunk extends RenderBlock{
byte CHUNK_SIZE = 32;
private Block[][][] BlockType = new Block[CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE];
static final float CUBE_LENGTH= RenderBlock.CUBE_LENGTH;
private static Texture texture = TextureLoad.getTexture();
private int VBOTextureHandle;
private int VBOVertexHandle;
//Texture Handle
public void drawChunk() {
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glEnable(GL15.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING);

    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
    GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());
    texture.bind();
    GL13.glActiveTexture(VBOTextureHandle);

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24 * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
public Chunk(int x, int y, int z, HeightMap height) {
    for(int chunkx=0; chunkx<CHUNK_SIZE; chunkx++) {
        for(int chunky=0; chunky<CHUNK_SIZE; chunky++) {
            for(int chunkz=0; chunkz<CHUNK_SIZE; chunkz++) {
                BlockType[chunkx][chunky][chunkz] = new BlockDirt();
            }
        }
    }
    VBOTextureHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    VBOVertexHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();

    makeChunk(x, y, z, height);
}
public void makeChunk(int startx, int starty, int startz, HeightMap map) {
    VBOVertexHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();  
    VBOTextureHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    FloatBuffer VertexPositionData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(CHUNK_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE*(3 * 4 * 6));
    FloatBuffer VertexTextureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(CHUNK_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE*(4 * 4 * 6));
    for(int x=0; x<CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<CHUNK_SIZE; y++) {
            for(int z=0; z<CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                VertexPositionData.put(putVertices((float) (startx + x)* CUBE_LENGTH, (float) (starty + y) * CUBE_LENGTH, (float) (startz + z) * CUBE_LENGTH));
                VertexTextureData.put(TexturePos(getTexturePosX(BlockType[x][y][z]), getTexturePosY(BlockType[x][y][z])));
            }
        }
    }
    VertexPositionData.flip();
    VertexTextureData.flip();

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexPositionData,
            GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexTextureData,
            GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

}
```

RenderCube Class

```
public class RenderBlock extends Block{
static final public float CUBE_LENGTH=2;
Block block = new Block();
//verticies
public float[] putVertices(float x, float y, float z) {
    float offset = CUBE_LENGTH / 2;
    return new float[] {
            // BOTTOM QUAD(DOWN=+Y)
            x + offset, y + offset, z, 
            x - offset, y + offset, z,
            x - offset, y + offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            x + offset, y + offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            // TOP!
            x + offset, y - offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            x - offset, y - offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            x - offset, y - offset, z,
            x + offset, y - offset, z,
            // FRONT QUAD
            x + offset, y + offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH, 
            x - offset, y + offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH, 
            x + offset, y - offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            // BACK QUAD
            x + offset, y - offset, z, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z,
            x - offset, y + offset, z,
            x + offset, y + offset, z,
            // LEFT QUAD
            x - offset, y + offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            x - offset, y + offset, z,
            x - offset, y - offset, z, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            // RIGHT QUAD
            x + offset, y + offset, z,
            x + offset, y + offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            x + offset, y - offset, z - CUBE_LENGTH,
            x + offset, y - offset, z };
}

public float[] TexturePos(int posx, int posy) {
    return new float[]{
            posx,posy,
            posx+32,posy,
            posx+32,posy+32,
            posx,posy+32
        };
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());
texture.bind();
```

to

```
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
```

Also, when using multiple textures, or some textured shapes and other's blank or just colored, after

```
GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24 * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE);
```

add

```
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I'm not sure if this will work, I haven't tested it, and I don't know if this is what causing the error, but this should help with rendering the texture. It works for me anyways.